# List azure Workspaces By Resource Group in C# .NET

Tags: c#, rest, azure

How do I get the list of workspaces by ressource group ?

I found this Rest call : [List workspace by ressource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces/listbyresourcegroup)

The ressource to call is :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces?api-version=2018-04-01
```

under log analytics rest api documentation, but it seems like there is no equivalent to this call in azure .NET SDK .

Do I have to make the Rest call from my C# code using something like HttpClient or there is a more simple way to issue the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned two resource `OperationalInsights` and `Databricks` in your post, not clear which one you want to use, so I list both of them.

For `OperationalInsights`, you can download [Microsoft.Azure.Management.OperationalInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.OperationalInsights/0.16.0-preview) to use the SDK.

While for `Databricks`, I don't find any SDK either in [.NET SDK document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.operationalinsights?view=azure-dotnet). Calling REST API is a standard way, and there seems no easier method AFAIK.

Using SDK or REST both require you to get necessary info(appId, secretKey, tenantId) by registering AD App and assigning role to application. Please follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application).

And then use code snippet below. Remeber to install [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/) to generate credential.

```
var appId = "ApplicationID";
var secretKey = "SecretKey";
var tenantId = "TenantID(aka DirectoryID)";
var subscriptionId = "SubscriptionId";
var resourceGroupName = "ResourceGroupName";

var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(appId, secretKey);
var tokenResponse = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential).Result;
var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;

//OperationalInsights
var opsClient = new OperationalInsightsManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(accessToken))
{
     SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
};
var workspaces = opsClient.Workspaces.ListByResourceGroupAsync(resourceGroupName).Result;


// Databricks
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://management.azure.com/");

     using (var response = await client.GetAsync(
                $"subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces?api-version=2018-04-01"))
     {
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
          Console.WriteLine(json);
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jerry , Thanks for the answer  you saved my day .

I was looking for the first part of your answer , do you have any ressource to get familiar with OperationalInsights nugget package types please ?

Comment: @ZackISSER Only got the [offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.operationalinsights?view=azure-dotnet), there seems few description about this resource.

Comment: Hi jerry , is there away to write cross-workspace queries using the OperationalInsightsManagementClient class ?  I posted this question one day ago :  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334286/cross-workspace-queries-in-azure-log-analytics-net-sdk

Comment: @ZackISSER ,Sorry for my long delay of response and also thanks for inviting me to offer suggestion, have added my solution.