# Cross-workspace queries in azure log analytics .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm using azure log analytics  .NET SDK to execute some log analytics queries.

The nugget package I'm using for this SDK is [Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights/).

This allows me to issue some simple queries like in the following  code sample :

Authentication & Simple query :

```
partial class QueryProvider
{

    private OperationalInsightsDataClient _operationalInsightsDataClient;


    private async void Authenticate()
    {

        // Retrieving the credentials and settings data from the app settings .
        var domain = SettingsHelpers.PullSettingsByKey("domain");
        var clientId = SettingsHelpers.PullSettingsByKey("clientId");
        var workspaceId = SettingsHelpers.PullSettingsByKey("workspaceId");

        var authEndpoint = SettingsHelpers.PullSettingsByKey("authEndpoint");
        var clientSecret = SettingsHelpers.PullSettingsByKey("clientSecret");
        var tokenAudience = SettingsHelpers.PullSettingsByKey("tokenAudience");


        // Authenticating to the azure log analytics service .
        var azureActiveDirectorySettings = new ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings
        {
            AuthenticationEndpoint = new Uri(authEndpoint),
            TokenAudience = new Uri(tokenAudience),
            ValidateAuthority = true
        };


        var credentials = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync
        (
              domain
            , clientId
            , clientSecret
            , azureActiveDirectorySettings
        );


        _operationalInsightsDataClient = new OperationalInsightsDataClient(credentials);
        _operationalInsightsDataClient.WorkspaceId = workspaceId;

    }


    public async Task<string> LogAnalyticsSamleQuery()
    {

        var query = @"Usage 
                    | where TimeGenerated > ago(3h)
                    | where DataType == 'Perf' 
                    | where QuantityUnit == 'MBytes'
                    | summarize avg(Quantity) by Computer
                    | sort by avg_Quantity desc nulls last";


       var jsonResult = await _operationalInsightsDataClient.QueryAsync(query);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResult.Results);

    } 
}
```

Now I want to write a method that runs a cross-workspace query , I get the workspaces Ids dynamically and I want to build o query that references all those workspaces .

I did not find any sample in the doc to build such queries .

I found an attribute of OperationalInsightDataClient class called  AdditionalWorkspaces but it's unclear how to use it to achieve the goal .

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ListWorkspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237886/list-azure-workspaces-by-resource-group-in-c-sharp-net) method, store workspace `Id` , `CustomerId`or `Name` in List.

```
var ws = new List<string>();
foreach (var w in workspaces)
{
     ws.Add(w.Id);
}
```

`AdditionalWorkspaces` is used to store workspaces you want to query, but has no influence on the query result.

```
_operationalInsightsDataClient.AdditionalWorkspaces = ws;
```

To cross-workspace query, add the list of workspace-Id in the query method.

```
var jsonResult = await _operationalInsightsDataClient.QueryAsync(query,null, _operationalInsightsDataClient.AdditionalWorkspaces);
```

Comment: What I still dont get is the role of the AdditionalWorkspaces  property , if is required to provide q list of workspaces id QueryAsync to every time we need to run a query

Comment: @ZackISSER  Maybe it just wants to offer a uniform management for variable to be used but not necessary actually.

Comment: Hi Jerry,  is there is a simple way to get the le list of workspaces and the SourceComputerId for each workspace. I need to collect this data , each workspaceId and the list of sourceComputerId for each workspace.